# Python-Which command is better for changing the file extension?

Tags: python, performance, coding-style, standards

I am trying to change an extension for a file, and I got two options.

`os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(g_filename))[0] + ".new"`

`os.path.basename(g_filename).split('.')[0] + ".new"`

Both gives the same output. So i am getting a new file called `oldfile.new` from `oldfile.old`

No possibility of having too many `'.'` in the file name.

Which is better of these two? What is the thumb rule (if any)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you implement them, they are different. Use correct one:

```
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename('a.b.c'))[0] + '.new'
'a.b.new'
>>> os.path.basename('a.b.c').split('.')[0] + ".new"
'a.new'
```

**Update**

One can replace `split` call with `rsplit(..., 1)`, and result will be similar to `splitext`:

```
>>> os.path.basename('a.b.c').rsplit('.', 1)[0] + ".new"
'a.b.new'
```

But difference between functions still exsits, as `splitext` treats filenames starting with a dot as having no extension, most probably since those are special for unix based os:

```
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename('.a'))[0] + '.new'
'.a.new'
>>> os.path.basename('.a').rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.new'
'.new'
```

Comment: +1 for providing clarity on command usage

Answer (score 2):

The first one is the better of the two.

The second one would get tripped up if the filename had two or more periods in it.